# Drupal add menu link to user menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

In Drupal 7 module development, supposedly by using the hook_menu function, how can I add menu link to the user menu? 
[Here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LmCp.png)

I found easily it in the administration but I can't find how to do it programmatically, I haven't found any menu type that would fit this situation. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify the `menu_name` in the data returned by your [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x):

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['example'] = array(
    'title' => 'Example Page',
    'page callback' => 'example_page',
    'menu_name' => 'user-menu', // << Menu name
    'weight' => 12, // << position
    'access arguments' => array(
      'access content',
    ),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

By default, it is added in the Navigation menu.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem to work to me. I cleared the cache after this but the item won't show. If I want to the menu link to send the user to another page, do i simply put "drupal_goto("url") to the callback function?

Comment: Yes, you could do `drupal_goto("user")` to redirect to the user page.

Comment: I've checked and it's working as expected. Could you post your `$item` please?

Comment: Oh, then it doesn't seem to work, the link won't show -- I'll update the post

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what went wrong before.. So I copied your solution and edited it and now it works! Thank you for your time.